# NSAutoReleaseNoPool() error, plus a weird bug

Tags: objective-c, nsautoreleasepool

I have the following code, and am having some problems with it. Any help would be appreciated.  When I run the code, I got an error:

> `2010-11-11 12:28:15.352 addressBook[25563:a0f] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100111010 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking`

I tried adding an autorelease pool, but it gave me much worse errors (that stopped the program running at all), but maybe I did it wrong?

Also, for some reason, after it prompts for a name input, it instantly prompts for the address input before I have a chance to enter anything.. but it only does this on the first contact I'm adding. I have no idea how this could happen..

```
how many address would you like to input?
Running…
3
2010-11-11 12:28:15.352 addressBook[25563:a0f] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100111010 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Please input the name of contact
Please input the address of contact
john doe
Please input the birthday of contact 
500 E. Main
```

so on, so forth.

```
printf("how many address would you like to input?\n");
int numAddresses;
scanf("%i", &numAddresses);
if(numAddresses<1) return 0;
NSMutableArray * arrayOfBooks = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < numAddresses; ++i) {
    book * f = [[book alloc] init];
    [arrayOfBooks addObject:f];
    [f release];

}
unsigned count = [arrayOfBooks count];
while (count--) {
    id object = [arrayOfBooks objectAtIndex:count];

    printf("Please input the name of contact\n");
    char inputString1[50];
    if(fgets(inputString1, sizeof inputString1, stdin)){
        [object setName: inputString1];
    }

    printf("Please input the address of contact\n");
    char inputString2[50];
    fgets(inputString2, sizeof inputString2, stdin);
    [object setAddress: inputString2];

    printf("Please input the birthday of contact \n");
    char inputString3[50];
    fgets(inputString3, sizeof inputString3, stdin);
    [object setBirthday: inputString3];

    printf("Please input the phone number of contact \n");
    char inputString4[50];
    fgets(inputString4, sizeof inputString4, stdin);
    [object setPhoneNumber: inputString4];

    [object print]; 

}

return 0;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Objective-C, you must wrap the whole main function with an auto release pool. You use it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   // real code here

   [pool drain];
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed at least one of my problems.